# How to convert 64 bit hex value to double in c?

Tags: c, embedded, embedded-linux

I'm using a gps module through which I'm getting the string

```
"0x3f947ae147ae147b"
```

which I need to convert to `double`. The expected value is `0.02`.

I referred the following website for the reference

[https://gregstoll.com/~gregstoll/floattohex/](https://gregstoll.com/%7Egregstoll/floattohex/)

How I can convert value in the C?

Comment: Not without losing significance, if there are more than 53 consecutive bits with at least one bit set. The value in the question contains 62 such bits.

Comment: I didnt got your point can you please elaborate more?

Comment: `gps module` what gps module? `embedded embedded-linux` What linux and what embedded platform are you using? `in the C?` What compiler are you using?

Comment: @WeatherVane I think that is the hex representation of the encoding of the expected value in IEEE 754 double.

Comment: I'm using NT103.SMT module which will send NMEI strings continiously in which one of the parameter value i'm getting hex value "0x3f947ae147ae147b" so the according to the datasheet i need to convert the same into double.

Comment: Apologies, at first I thought the question was asking how to convert a large hexadecimal *integer* into a `double`.

Comment: @OmkarDixit You have my sympathies for this difficulty.  I've parsed lots of different NMEA (not "NMEI") sentences in my time, but I've *never* come across one that encoded floating-point as hex like that.  Very strange.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

3F947AE147AE147B<sub>16</sub> is the encoding for an IEEE-754 binary64 (a.k.a. “double precision”) datum with value 0.0200000000000000004163336342344337026588618755340576171875. Supposing your C implementation uses that format for `double` and has 64-bit integers with the same endianness, you can decode it (not convert it) by copying its bytes into a `double` and printing them:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(void)
{
    char *string = "0x3f947ae147ae147b";

    //  Set errno to zero before using strtoull.
    errno = 0;
    char *end;
    unsigned long long t = strtoull(string, &end, 16);

    //  Test whether stroull did not accept all characters.
    if (*end)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,
            "Error, string \"%s\", is not a proper hexadecimal numeral.\n",
            string);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //  Move the value to a 64-bit unsigned integer.
    uint64_t encoding = t;

    /*  Test whether the number is too large, either because strtoull reported
        an error or because it does not fit in a uint64_t.
    */
    if ((t == ULLONG_MAX && errno) || t != encoding)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error, string \"%s\", is bigger than expected.\n",
            string);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //  Copy the bytes into a double.
    double x;
    memcpy(&x, &encoding, sizeof x);
    printf("%.9999g\n", x);
}
```

This should output “0.0200000000000000004163336342344337026588618755340576171875”.

If your C implementation does not support this format, you can decode it:

- Separate the 64 bits into *s*, *e*, *f*, where *s* is the leading bit, *e* is the next 11 bits, and *f* is the remaining 52 bits.
- If *e* is 2047 and *f* is zero, report the value is +∞ or −∞, according to whether *s* is 0 or 1, and stop.
- If *e* is 2047 and *f* is not zero, report the value is a NaN (Not a Number) and stop.
- If *e* is not zero, add 2<sup>52</sup> to *f*. If *e* is zero, change it to one.
- The magnitude of the represented value is *f*•2<sup>−52</sup>•2<sup>*e*−1023</sup>, and its sign is + or − according to whether *s* is 0 or 1.

Comment: I really appreciate for your responce. In my code basically I'm using "char string[]" variable to store the hex value. So i tried to send the &string to the memcpy as follows "memcpy(&x, &string, sizeof x);" but then i found that the values were not correct.

Comment: @OmkarDixit Eric assumed you knew how to convert the string `"0x3f947ae147ae147b"` to the integer `0x3f947ae147ae147b`.  You need the `strtoull` function for this.  See my answer for further details.

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to convert a string of digits like `"0x3f947ae147ae147b"` into an actual integer is with one of the "strto" functions.  Since you have 64 bits, and you're not interested in treating them as a signed integer (since you're about to, instead, try to treat them as a `double`), the appropriate choice is `strtoull`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char *str = "0x3f947ae147ae147b";
uint64_t x = strtoull(str, NULL, 16);
```

Now you have your integer, as you can verify by doing

```
printf("%llx\n", x);
```

But now the question is, how do you treat those bits as an IEEE-754 `double` value, instead of an integer?  There are at least three ways to do it, in increasing levels of portability.

(1) Use pointers.  Take a pointer to your integer value `x`, change it do a `double` pointer, then indirect on it, forcing the compiler to (try to) treat the bits of `x` as if they were a `double`:

```
double *dp = (double *)&x;
double d = *dp;
printf("%f\n", d);
```

This was once a decent and simple way to do it, but it is no longer legal as it runs afoul of the "[strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)".  It might work for you, or it might not.  Theoretically this sort of technique can also run into issues with alignment.  For these reasons, this technique is not recommended.

(2) Use a union:

```
union u { uint64_t x; double d; } un;
un.x = strtoull(str, NULL, 16);
printf("%f\n", un.d);
```

Opinions differ on whether this technique is 100% strictly legal.  I believe it's fine in C, but it may not be in C++.  I'm not aware of machines where it won't work.

(3) Use `memcpy`:

```
#include <string.h>

uint64_t x = strtoull(str, NULL, 16);
double d;
memcpy(&d, &x, 8);
printf("%f\n", d);
```

This works by, literally, copying the individual bytes of the `unsigned long int` value `x` into the bytes of the `double` variable `d`.  This is 100% portable (as long as `x` and `d` are the same size).  I used to think it was wasteful, due to the extra function call, but these days it's a generally recommended technique, and I'm told that modern compilers are smart enough to recognize what you're trying to do, and emit perfectly efficient code (that is, just as efficient as techniques (1) or (2)).

Now, one other portability concern is that this all assumes that type `double` on your machine is in fact implemented using the same IEEE-754 double-precision format as your incoming hex string representation.  That's actually a very safe assumption these days, although it's not strictly guaranteed by the C standards.  If you like to be particularly careful about type correctness, you might add the lines

```
#include <assert.h>

assert(sizeof(uint64_t) == sizeof(double));
```

and change the `memcpy` call (if that's what you end up using) to

```
memcpy(&d, &x, sizeof(double));
```

(But note that these last few changes only guard against unexpected system-specific discrepancies in the *size* of type `double`, not its representation.)

One further point.  Note that one technique which will most definitely *not* work is the superficially obvious

```
d = (double)x;
```

That line would perform an actual *conversion* of the value 0x3f947ae147ae147b.  It won't just reinterpret the bits.  If you try it, you'll get an answer like 4581421828931458048.000000.  Where did *that* come from?  Well, 0x3f947ae147ae147b in decimal is 4581421828931458171, and the closest value that type `double` can represent is 4581421828931458048.  (Why can't type `double` represent the integer 4581421828931458171 exactly?  Because it's a 62-bit number, and type `double` has at most 53 bits of precision.)

Comment: Re “It might work on your machine. (It seems to work on mine.)”: Whether aliasing “works” is not a function of the machine. It depends on the C implementation. There is **nothing** about an Intel processor or an ARM processor any other processor that will make aliasing work or not work. It depends solely on how the C compiler (or other parts of the C implementation) process the program.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. I really appriciate. I have used now the 3rd option.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Point.  Answer updated.